# INSERT Email address, but ignore (if exists || if suffix = existing suffix && sender name =existingsender name) MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, email

I'm trying to insert a query into mysql using php, but to have restrictions.

```
$sql_insert = "
INSERT IGNORE 
    into `email` 
        (`message`,`useremail`,`senderemail`) 
    VALUES 
        ('$emailmessage','$email_address','$fromaddress') 
WHERE
";
```

$fromaddress is the value I want to make the constraints.

Here's an example

```
"Zazzle" <sender-1234@zazzle.com>
```

Don't insert if `sender-1234@zazzle.com` is in the senderemail field
Don't insert if `"Zazzle"` is in the field and if `@zazzle.com` is also in the field.

Comment: Simplest solution: put unique keys on the fields that should be unique.

Comment: So for this logic to work, I'd need to create an extra database value (or 2) containing the email suffix and the sender name.  I'm not sure if that's efficient since I'm already storing the email_address.  I'll take a look and see what kind of load it does.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you can pull the email apart and then check the database to see if it exists in the database using preg_match. If using the example:

```
--"Zazzle" <sender-1234@zazzle.com>
```

---

```
$atIndex = strrpos($fromaddress, "@");
$nameIndex = strrpos($fromaddress, "<");
$domain = substr($fromaddress, $atIndex+1); # returns zazzle.com
$local = substr($fromaddress, $nameIndex+1, $atIndex); # returns sender-123
$name = substring($fromaddress, 0, $nameIndex-1); # returns "Zazzle"
```

from there all you have to do is do a select/where query and if no results then to insert.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM email WHERE senderemail like '".$domain."'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

---

### OR

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM email";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
     if(preg_match($domain, $row['senderemail'])) { $isPresent = true; }
}
```

---

Preg match will look for the strings in the individual returned value and if present set a value to true. Then you can compare that value to be true/false and then to update your database.